# Using async in express

Tags: express, async-await, endpoint

Below is my rest API endpoint /signup. The problem I'm having now is that the endpoint does not stop after validateEmail. Even after it failed email form-validation and res.send() is done, the endpoint continues. So I'm keep getting the error 'Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.'. I would like to be able to finish the endpoint inside its functions like validateEmail , checkEmailInUse, makeUser, and so on.

```
router.post("/signup", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const users = req.app.get("users");
  validateEmail(res, email);
  await checkEmailInUse(res, users, email);
  const user = await makeUser(res, users, email, password);
  res.send({ message: "POST signup request OK", user });
});

function validateEmail(res, email) {
  const isEmail = emailFilter.test(email);
  if (!isEmail) {
    res.status(400).send({
      error: {
        message: "Requested email is not email type",
        type: "FormatValidation",
        location: "validateEmail"
      }
    });
    return;
  }
}

async function checkEmailInUse(res, users, email) {
  const query = { email };
  try {
    const user = await users.findOne(query);
    if (user) {
      res.send({ message: "The email is already used" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send({
      error: {
        message: "Failed to find user",
        type: "DatabaseError",
        location: "checkEmailInUse"
      }
    });
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: does prepending 'return' in front of res.status().send() help?

Comment: No sir, I saw similar ideas through googling. I just changed from return res.status().send() to the way it its now.

Comment: I think I have to turn them to middlewares and use next() if validation is successful, and res.send() if not.

Comment: With the setup you have going here, 2 things come to mind.
1) assign validate email to return a boolean, then conditionally send an error based off of its value  2) is making validateEmail an a middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code keeps going after a failed validate because you call:

```
validateEmail(res, email);
```

and then your code just keeps going.  This is normal flow of control in Javascript.  Your function keeps executing lines of code until you `return` in the function.  The same issue is true for `checkEmailInUse()`.  If you want to sometimes send the response inside those functions and be done, then you need a return value from those functions that you can check and then use `if` statements to determine whether your code should do more or not.

Following your style of sending the error response inside the validation functions (which is not how I would probably structure things), you could return values from those functions and test those return values in the request handler like this:

```js
router.post("/signup", async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const users = req.app.get("users");
    if (validateEmail(res, email)) {
        if (await checkEmailInUse(res, users, email)) {
            const user = await makeUser(res, users, email, password);
            res.send({ message: "POST signup request OK", user });
        }
    }
  });

  function validateEmail(res, email) {
    const isEmail = emailFilter.test(email);
    if (!isEmail) {
      res.status(400).send({
        error: {
          message: "Requested email is not email type",
          type: "FormatValidation",
          location: "validateEmail"
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  async function checkEmailInUse(res, users, email) {
    const query = { email };
    try {
      const user = await users.findOne(query);
      if (user) {
        res.send({ message: "The email is already used" });
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;  
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send({
        error: {
          message: "Failed to find user",
          type: "DatabaseError",
          location: "checkEmailInUse"
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

But, I think you might find this is simpler if you get rid of the local functions because then when you send a response, you can just directly `return` from the main function and be done.  Here's how that could look:

```js
router.post("/signup", async (req, res, next) => {

    function err(res, message, type, location) {
        res.status(400).send({error: {message, type, location}});
    }

    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
        err(res, "Requested email is not email type", "FormatValidation", "validateEmail");
        return;
    }
    const users = req.app.get("users");
    try {
        const user = await users.findOne({email});
        if (user) {
            res.send({ message: "The email is already used" });
            return;
        }
    } catch(e) {
        err(res, "Failed to find user", "DatabaseError", "checkEmailInUse");
        return;
    }
    try {
        const user = await makeUser(res, users, email, password);
        res.send({ message: "POST signup request OK", user });
    } catch(e) {
        err(res, "Failed to make user", "DatabaseError", "makeUser");
    }
}
```